# Can't connect to interpreter via SSH (WSL)

Tags: ssh, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to add new python interpreter via ssh (WSL), I get an error: Connection to sshuser@localhost:22 failed: Error finalising cipher.

[image]

I have the last version of Pycharm. I tried to connect to WSL via ssh using Putty and it works.

I have found this post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000192424-Cant-connect-via-shh-to-choose-intepreter-WSL- This is a similar issue, but port changing was not helpful for me.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Sounds similar to [PY-29400](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29400), try this workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29400#focus=streamItem-27-2802310-0-0

Comment: Thank you @PavelKarateev! It saved my life!
I have renamed c.kdbx file and tried to connect again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to remove or rename c.kdbx file at the Pycharm config folder.
See details here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29400#focus=streamItem-27-2802310-0-0
Thanks for @PavelKarateev for quick and accurate response!